# How to read txt/csv line by line using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, loops

I have a couple of txt/csv files, I am trying to feed the each line in the file into my API commands in a loop.

eg: server.txt - first file contains servers and resource groups `server1, rg1
                                                          server2, rg2
                                                          server3, rg3` etc.

ips.txt - another file contains rules & ips `rule1, startip1, endip1
                                      rule2, startip2, endip2
                                      rule3, startip3, endip3` etc.

The issue is how to I set up powershell to each line in server.txt and also ips.txt within the same loop?

I had something like this before, but It doesnt seem to work well. Any thoughts?

```
$list=Get-Content "servers.txt"

foreach ($data in $list) {
    $server_name, $rg = $data -split ',' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'


    Write-Host "Checking if SQL server belongs in subscription"
    $check=$(az sql server list -g $rg --query "[?name == '$server_name'].name" -o tsv)
    Write-Host $check


    # Get current rules and redirect output to file
    az sql server firewall-rule list --resource-group "$rg" --server "$server_name" --output table | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation current-natrules.csv

    $new_rules=Get-Content "ips.txt"

    foreach ($data in $new_rules) {
        $rule_name, $start_ip, $end_ip = $data -split ',' -replace '^\s*|\s*$'

        # Create rule with new configs
        Write-Host "Assigning new firewall rules..."
        az sql server firewall-rule create --name "$rule_name" --server "$server_name" --resource-group "$rg" --start-ip-address "$start_ip" --end-ip-address "$end_ip" --output table
    }

    # Validating
    Write-Host "Printing new NAT rules to file..."
    az sql server firewall-rule list --resource-group "$rg" --server "$server_name" --output table | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation new-natrules.csv
}
```

Comment: I'd try my luck with `Import-Csv` and/or `ConvertFrom-String` before any manual parsing. Store the results in objects before processing to reuse them.

Comment: Use a different variable for the nested foreach, not the same

Comment: @LotPings smh, that did the trick. Works as expected now

Comment: @LotPings Please add an answer to let others know.